# segmentation fault during C library call in an assembly program

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I am experimenting on modifying assembly program by calling c library (add.c) from assembly, I ran into segmentation fault in movsd %xmm0, (%rax). Any idea to resolve this issue, I am new to assembly.

I have created library add.c which performs multiplication.
The call should be invoked from assembly.

My exp1.c looks like

> exp1.c is
>
> ```
> double *a,*b,*c;
> int main()
> {
> double a_d = 1.1;
> double b_d = 2.1;
> double c_d;
> c = &c_d;
> a = &a_d;
> b = &b_d;
> *c = (*a + *b);
> printf("\n%lf",*c);
> }
> ```

---

> ```
> add.c is
> ```

---

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> double add(double a_me, double b_me){
> double c = a_me*b_me;
> printf("\n%lf and %lf is %lf\n",a_me,b_me,c);
> return c;   }
> ```

---

> ```
> .file   "add.c"
>         .text
>         .globl  add
>         .type   add, @function
> add:
> .LFB0:
>         .cfi_startproc
>         pushq   %rbp
>         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
>         .cfi_offset 6, -16
>         movq    %rsp, %rbp
>         .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
>         movsd   %xmm0, -24(%rbp)
>         movsd   %xmm1, -32(%rbp)
>         movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm0
>         mulsd   -32(%rbp), %xmm0
>         movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)
>         movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
>         movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
>         movsd   -40(%rbp), %xmm0
>         popq    %rbp
>         .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
>         ret
>         .cfi_endproc
> .LFE0:
>         .size   add, .-add
>         .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
>         .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
> ```

---

> ```
> .file "exp1.c"
> .comm a,8,8
> .comm b,8,8
> .comm c,8,8
> .section .rodata
> .LC2:
> .string "\n%lf"
> .text
> .globl main
> .type main, @function
> main:
> .LFB0:
> .cfi_startproc
> pushq %rbp
> .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
> .cfi_offset 6, -16
> movq %rsp, %rbp
> .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
> subq $48, %rsp
> movabsq $4607632778762754458, %rax
> movq %rax, -24(%rbp)
> movabsq $4611911198408756429, %rax
> movq %rax, -16(%rbp)
> leaq -8(%rbp), %rax
> movq %rax, c(%rip)
> leaq -24(%rbp), %rax
> movq %rax, a(%rip)
> leaq -16(%rbp), %rax
> movq %rax, b(%rip)
> movq c(%rip), %rax
> movq a(%rip), %rdx
> movsd (%rdx), %xmm1
> movq b(%rip), %rdx
> movsd (%rdx), %xmm0
> #addsd %xmm1, %xmm0            # commented actual addition
> call add                       # added my library call here
> movsd %xmm0, (%rax)            # segmentation fault here
> movq c(%rip), %rax
> movq (%rax), %rax
> movq %rax, -40(%rbp)
> movsd -40(%rbp), %xmm0
> movl $.LC2, %edi
> movl $1, %eax
> call printf
> leave
> .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
> ret
> .cfi_endproc
> .LFE0:
> .size main, .-main
> .ident "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
> .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
> ```

Comment: The `add` function clobbers `%rax`, so storing into `(%rax)` segfaults.  Use a debugger to single-step.

Comment: You don't need to store and reload the return value in `%xmm0`.  You're just making things complicated for yourself by using un-optimized compiler output.  Compile with `-O2`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output, especially the link to Matt Godbolt's talk about looking at compiler output.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not allowed to use optimization flags, add.c is a kind of third party lib, I need to invoke that lib call from gcc generated assembly

Comment: Ok, then optimize the asm by hand yourself and remove the useless store/reload.  Is there some kind of requirement that the asm has to "look like" the source, instead of just producing the same result using any optimizations the "as-if" rule would let a compiler make?  You are allowed to optimize out the store/reload, right?  Because nothing in the C source depends on having `*c` in memory; a register is fine.

Comment: Or if that's not ok, then use a call-preserved register like `%rbx` for `double *c`.  (Don't forget to save/restore it so `main` doesn't clobber its caller's value).